# Printf comes out negative

Tags: c, negative-number

I'm new to programming and am trying to have my program take a given number, double it, then continue to double for however many days the user input. I made this loop and it works but the final number comes out negative. I'm not sure how I can stop it from coming out negative and would appreciate any help.

```
int main(void)
{

    int d;
    int s;
    float a;

    do
    {
        printf ("Please enter the amount of days in the month: ");
        d = GetInt();   
    } while (d > 31 || d < 28);

    do 
    { 
        printf("Please enter the amount of pennies you start will start with: ");
        s = GetInt();
    } while( s < 0);

    do 
    {    
        s = s * 2;
        d = d - 1;
        a = s / 100.0;
        printf("%f\n", a);

    } while(d > 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do `s` and `d` come from?  What are their initial values?

Comment: It would also be helpful to know what s, d and a are.  Are they 32bit integers?

Comment: post the `relevant` code - the definition and initial values of all the values at minimum

Comment: there's no such thing as `printf` in C#. Unless you coded that method yourself, in which case you should post that code as well.

Comment: You're probably encountering integer overflow. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

Comment: retaged as C. There is no printf in C#, and this relies on no feature in C++ that's not in C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
s=s*2;
```

(Though you should be sure to *always* initialize your variables, e.g. `s=0` before the loop.)

Integers don't have a special value for when the number gets larger than the storage type, so they [overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

Here's an example of that could happen. Imagine that we store integers as a series of 4 bits where the first bit means that a number is negative. If we then begin counting in our system, we get the following:

```
0000 = 0
0001 = 1
0010 = 2
0011 = 3
0100 = 4
0101 = 5
0110 = 6
0111 = 7
1000 = -0
1001 = -1
1010 = -2
```

So you can see that the numbers keep on growing inside the computer, but what they translate to suddenly becomes negative when the most significant bit is flipped on.

Computers use all kinds of different schemes for storing negative numbers, but [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) is common. It's more clever than the system I've used to explain things here, but the essential point remains the same: when numbers get too big they become negative. In the case of an `int` the cross-over point is often when you hit `2^31`, or 2147483648.

A workaround is to use `unsigned int`, which roughly doubles the largest number you can represent, or `long`, `long long`, `unsigned long`, or `unsigned long long`. Remember, this won't solve your problem, it will just give you larger numbers you can work with before a problem appears.

You can find the largest usable value using the [`limits.h`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/) header file; for an `int` it is `INT_MAX`.

Comment: With 32-bit numbers, `unsigned int` would actually solve the OP's problem, since no month has more than 31 days ;) (But that's an exceptional situation here.)

Answer (score 1):

```
2^31 = 2147483648
```

If there are more than 30 days you will overflow an integer even starting with 1 penny and doubling the value. If you start with a larger number of pennies you overflow sooner.

When an integer overflows, it displays as a negative value.  Per suggestion below it is undefined behavior.  Which is a term programmers use, and new folks do not understand well.

Comment: You're mistaken; When an expression results in a number that's too large to be expressed in it's type, the behaviour is undefined. `int x = INT_MAX + 1;`, for example, is undefined behaviour. Talking about that which is "common" doesn't encourage solutions that are "portable".

Comment: @modifiable lvalue - you are completely correct.  But that does not make a brusque "this is UB" a good answer for a newbie.  It is not good at all.  Because it makes someone who does not have a clue, then be forced to look up undefined behavior and wonder what it really means.  In this case integer overflow blows away the contents of the variable so you get garbage.  That is what UB means - in plain language: anything can happen. So the program is "not even wrong", as they say.  As string theorists say....

Comment: ... So you understand why "When an integer overflows, it displays as a negative value" belongs in a *bad answer*, yet you settle for it anyway. In the real world, this undefined behaviour has had the effect of saturation, signal throwing and wrapping (which is the behaviour you describe). Would "a good answer" contain misleading information?

Answer (score 1):

Section 6.5p5 of the C standard:

> If an exceptional condition occurs during the evaluation of an
>   expression (that is, if the result is not mathematically defined or
>   not in the range of representable values for its type), the behavior
>   is undefined.

What this says is that any `int` expression that is greater than `INT_MAX`, or less than `INT_MIN` will cause problems. Those problems aren't defined, so you can't handle them; It's best to avoid things like that. In your case, the calculation wraps into negative values as explained above. That isn't required, however. Perhaps if you were to compile and run this on a different system, with a different compiler, your program may crash, or it may seem to work as expected, somehow representing an infinite set of values in a finite storage space, or a chicken may run around headless for a few minutes... Who knows?

You can avoid this problem by carefully choosing a type that has a wider range, as is covered in the other answers, and enforcing a ceiling value on your inputs so that no overflow is possible. Another method would be to use an arbitrary precision arithmetic library such as [GNU MP Bignum](http://gmplib.org/) which shouldn't overflow.

Comment: Now this is far, far superior to your comments.  Your comment amounted to a 'this is UB', so take it or leave it. Keep doing this kind of answer: +1.  We have way too many short, useless, haughty, and even nasty comments.  None of which get anybody anywhere.  One point: there is a difference between being perfectly correct and communicating, this post shows communicating, your comments did not.  IMO.